# How to change colors for any object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change color for every instantiate in C# in unity for every object that created
I don't want that the previous object that created with the same prefab also change his color only for created
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of example about this topic.

But I am assuming you want to instantiate objects with different(random) colors.

**Instantiate object:**

```
  GameObject go = Instantiate(myPrefab, newVector3(x,y,z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

**You can change color like this:**

```
 go.GetComponent <MeshRenderer> ().material.color = newColor (Random.Range (0f, 1f), Random.Range (0f, 1f), Random.Range (0f, 1f), Random.Range (0f, 1f));
```

**Do not forget:**
Colours are 0 to 1 not 0 to 255.

Comment: you need to add ’f' after each number, otherwise you will always get zero

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you instantiate a GameObject, you can assign (change) the color by simply accessing render and material:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 255, 0);
```

Comment: Colors values are between 0 and 1 (as floats)

Comment: Thanks for everyone I have more question and it will be next the dashboard